Selenium Python || How to click on Toggle button based on its status
Could you please help me with below HTML and selenium?
<div id="container_elm_guest_code_auto_generate" class="cm-2 rounded bg-white setting-card highlightable">
    <div class="p-4">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="setting-info">
                <div class="setting_title">Auto-generate guest code</div>
            </div>
            <div class="setting-control d-flex justify-content-end">
                <label class="setting_toggle">
                    <input id="elm_guest_code_auto_generate" class="toggle-checkbox" type="checkbox">
                    <div class="toggle-switch"></div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

I am trying to click on the toggle button by id "elm_guest_code_auto_generate" and here is my python code:
toggle_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "elm_guest_code_auto_generate")))

# Check if the toggle button is inactive
if "checked" not in toggle_button.get_attribute("outerHTML"):
    # If the toggle button is inactive, click on it to activate it
    toggle_button.click()
    print("Toggle button activated.")
else:
    print("Toggle button is already active.")

and I am getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\muraril\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\GuestProfileRules\GuestProfileRule.py", line 73, in <module>
    toggle_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "elm_guest_code_auto_generate")))
  File "C:\Users\muraril\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 105, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 


Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea. Edit your question and add the code/HTML as text, properly formatted.

Is the INPUT tag actually visible or is it one of these hidden elements that's linked to another visible element? Have you checked if it's inside an IFRAME, etc.? A link to the page would really help here.

@JeffC - Thank you for educating me regarding the Screenshot.
I know it's not an iFRAME, however not sure of if it's hidden or not, Can you please help me identify it.

Fix the HTML in your question.

@JeffC - removed the screenshot and pasted the HTML text

Can you post a link to the page?

Yes, I can however, it would need username and password to reach there, hence no use of it. :(

Without seeing the page it's hard to know for sure but I would guess that the INPUT is actually not visible and that's why it's timing out. Many sites/pages use this to hide the standard INPUT look and replace it with some fancy checkboxes, radio buttons, etc. I would try to click other elements around it to see what clicks actually trigger the checkmark. I would start by clicking the LABEL that surrounds the INPUT.
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label.setting_toggle"))).click()

